# Send file to user

Tags: php

How to send a file to the user so they can choose directory and file name. The code below let the user download the file but it does not allow for directory selection in Firefox. How can I fix it?

```
// We'll be outputting a PDF
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
// It will be called downloaded.pdf
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');
// The PDF source is in original.pdf
readfile('original.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

`Edit` | `Preferences` | `Applications` | `PDF Document` | `Always Ask`

Comment: Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, still doesn't work. "Always Ask" had been already set, BTW.

Answer (score 0):

This is a setting in the browser. You cannot force this through you PHP code. To change the settings, go to:

`Edit > Preferences > Main > Downloads` and check `Always ask me where to save files`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
  header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
```